# Phabricator - arc lint is not working even after I have Included an Linter Engine in .arconfig file

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

1. I created a JSHintLinter in the arcanist folder which is in `Users/vignesh.s/arc/arcanist`
2. This is my `.arcconfig` file.

```js
{
  "project_id": "convert",
  "load": [
    "/Users/vignesh.s/arc/arcanist/src/lint/engine/JsLintEngine.php"
  ],
  "lint.engine": "JsLintEngine"
}
```

3. When I run `arc lint` it says this error

> Usage Exception: No lint engine configured for this project. Edit '.arcconfig' to specify a lint engine, or create an '.arclint' file.

4. But when I run using `arc lint -engine JsLintEngine`, it simply works

Can you tell me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `.arcconfig` file is probably not being read. Usually, this is because you've accidentally put it in the wrong place. To troubleshoot this:

- Make sure `arc` is up to date (by running `arc upgrade`).
- Use `arc lint --trace` to see where configuration is loaded from.

The first few lines of output should show the `.arcconfig` file being loaded, with a message similar to this one:

```
...
Working Copy: Reading .arcconfig from "/path/to/project/.arcconfig".
...
```

If `arc` can not find a `.arcconfig` file, you will see a message like this instead:

```
...
Working Copy: Unable to find .arcconfig in any of these locations: /path/to/project/.arcconfig.
...
```

If you see that second message, move your `.arcconfig` file from where ever you currently have it to the specified location.

Comment: Thanks a lot Evan. arcanist could not able to find the path. It got fixed now. :)